# I cant find settings on my PC

Tags: settings, system-settings

I need the Ubuntu settings app for a reason. but I can't find it on the software list please give me the solution!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package name of the Settings app in Ubuntu is *gnome-control-center*. It can be installed with `sudo apt install gnome-control-center`

This package contains configuration applets for the GNOME desktop,  allowing to set accessibility configuration, desktop fonts, keyboard and mouse properties, sound setup, desktop theme and background, user interface properties, screen resolution, and other GNOME parameters.

It also contains a front end to these applets, which can also be accessed with the GNOME panel or the Nautilus file manager.

Comment: Thaks. It works!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said which version of Ubuntu you're using, but assuming it's a recent version of Ubuntu Desktop:

Click on the area at the top right (usually Power button, loudspeaker and connectivity icons) and a drop-down menu has 'Settings'.

[image]

[image]

Other ways to access it:

- Click on the grid at the bottom left; Settings should have an icon (it may not be on the first page - scroll through the pages using your mouse wheel or clicking on the dots at the bottom)
- Hit the Super (Windows) key and type 'Settings' and it should present itself (thanks @Hannu)
- In the terminal, type `/usr/bin/gnome-control-center` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: ... or hit the Super (Win) key and start typing `Settings`